# If a string is not matching one of 3 option in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string-comparison

This is the code I used to have to check if `$A` doesn't match `$B`

```
if($A!=$B) {
    $set = array();
    echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set));
    //echo print_r($_SERVER);
    exit;
}
```

Now I need the opposite of this condition: (`$A` need to match one of these `$B`,`$C` or `$D`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple shortcut to seeing if a value matches one of multiple values you can put the values to be compared against (`$B`, `$C`, and `$D`) into an array and then use `in_array()` to see if the original value (`$A`) matches any of them.

```
if (in_array($A, [$B, $C, $D])) {
   // ...
}
```

If you don't want it to match *any* of `$B`, `$C`, or `$D` just use `!`:

```
if (!in_array($A, [$B, $C, $D])) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_search

```
$B = 'B';
$C = 'C';
$D = 'D';

//match B
$A = 'B';

$options = [$B, $C, $D];

if (false !== ($index = array_search($A, $options ))) {
     echo "Match: {$index} '{$options[$index]}'";
}
```

Output

```
Match: 0 'B'
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6db62e47a24e273d5784c3883b4324f5bbebf1a9)

The nice thing here is you can set the `$index` and use that to tell which one matched later.

Note you have to use `false !==` because array search returns the index where the match happened at, so it can happen on the first array element which is index `0`.  As we know PHP can treat `0` as `false` (in this case the condition would fail when it should pass). However, when we use the strict type check PHP also compares the type and INT `0` is not BOOL `false` (which passes the condition).

for reference.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Another probably the most efficient way is to use isset, and use keys instead of values:

```
$options = [$B=>1,$C=>1,$D=>1]; //values don't matter
if(!isset($options[$A])){
    //....
}
```

Comment: Why would the index matter if you are building the array solely for the purpose of matching the value against multiple operands?

Comment: This may not be exactly what the OP is looking for, but it works and is handy to know

Comment: @Dharman Who knows?  It was just another way to solve the same problem.  You could even do `array_flip` (or build it with keys) and then do `isset($array[$A])` if you really wanted to, or even `array_intersect` etc..